# Wordpress 301 Redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I have got one Wordpress blog site and I use permalink as:

```
%category%/%postname%.html
```

I want a change as:

```
%postname%.html
```

And now old urls (https://www.example.com/category/post-name.html) 301 redirect to (https://www.example.com/post-name.html).

How can I redirect with use .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to wp-admin, then /settings, then /permalinks and select "Post name". More info on that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

For 301 redirects you can write your own to your htaccess file but this is probably not as easy as using a plugin like Simple 301 Redirects.